# Starting a new activity after completing facebook login android with details stored in shared preference

Tags: android, android-facebook

This is my facebook activity to perform login..I have successfully logged in but my problem is I want to store the first name , last name , facebook id in shared preference and I would like to move on to a new activity where I display all the details stored in shared preference.

I'm able to display the details but the details is stored only when the user logs in the second time.

The first time when the user login its show me a null pointer exception in my landing Activity.

```
public class MainFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;


private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private TextView textView, txtView_Id, txtView_fn, txtView_ln;
private ImageView profilePic;
private String id, fn, ln;
public AccessToken accessToken;

private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        try {
            //session.logoutUser();
            displayMessage(profile);
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

    }
};

public MainFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());


    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

        }
    };

    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
            try {
                displayMessage(currentProfile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    profileTracker.startTracking();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    // Session Manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txtView_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
    txtView_fn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    txtView_ln = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    profilePic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);


}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}

private void displayMessage(Profile profile) throws IOException {
    if (profile != null) {
        id = profile.getId();
        // thread.start();
        textView.setText(profile.getName());
        txtView_Id.setText(profile.getId());
        txtView_fn.setText(profile.getFirstName());
        txtView_ln.setText(profile.getLastName());
        id = profile.getId();
        fn = profile.getFirstName();
        ln = profile.getLastName();
        session.createLoginSession(fn, id, ln);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    profileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    try {
        displayMessage(profile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

my landing Activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SessionManager session;
    private TextView fn , ln,id,name;
    private Button logout;
    private ImageView profilePic;
    private String ids;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    SessionManager sessionManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        session =new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id);
        fn=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        ln=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        profilePic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        logout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        sessionManager=new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
       // session.logoutUser();
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        String firstName=user.get(SessionManager.KEY_FIRST_NAME);
        String lastName=user.get(SessionManager.KEY_LAST_NAME);
        ids=user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
        /**  String image=user.get(SessionManager.KEY_IMAGE);
        Bitmap bitmap=decodeBase64(image);
        profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap); **/
        id.setText(ids);
        fn.setText(firstName);
        ln.setText(lastName);
        //Log.e("FN :", firstName);
        //Log.e("LN :", lastName);
        //Log.e("ID :", ids);
     new Images().execute();
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sessionManager.logoutUser();

            }
        });

       // bitmap=getPhotoFacebook(ids);
       // profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



    }



    public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        return BitmapFactory
                .decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }

    public Bitmap getPhotoFacebook(final String id) {

        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        final String nomimg = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large";
        URL imageURL = null;

                try {
                    imageURL = new URL(nomimg);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    //connection.getInputStream();
                   // connection.getInputStream();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;

            }



   // session.createLoginSession(firstName,id ,lastName );  **/

    private class Images extends AsyncTask<Void , Void , Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

           bitmap=getPhotoFacebook(ids);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }




}

11-28 10:57:01.615 9917-9917/com.wom.www.womfb W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41570d58)
```

11-28 10:57:01.625 9917-9917/com.wom.www.womfb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.wom.www.womfb, PID: 9917
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wom.www.womfb/com.wom.www.womfb.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5154)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
                                                                     at com.wom.www.womfb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5154) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596) 
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: KishuDroid my log cat is not showing any error. my problem is I'm not able to store the values(first name , last name and id)  when the user logs in the first time. My doubt is I just wanted to know where at which point of code should i store the values in shared preference.